# Linux, Eclipse C++, how to connect ffmpeg libs to your project?

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse, ffmpeg

So I downloaded FFmpeg from svn. Compiled and installed into system. in /usr/local it created ./lib and ./include. one with includes and one with libs in form of *.a files.

I downloaded eclipse Helios for C++ and created new simple project. I included ffmpeg headers into my C++ file. in project properties in C/C++Build in settings I declared ffmpeg libs (Library search path was declared)

I wrote some simple code that calls functions from headers.

But for all ffmpeg functions I used it gave me errors of eclipse not seeing ffmpeg.

So I wonder - how to connect ffmpeg libs to my project (or may be there is any way to compile ffmpeg not into .a and it would work with .so)?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on my **ubuntu 12.04** and I fixed it by compiling ffmpeg and x264 in this way:
I removed the folders of ffmpeg and x264 and then typed this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove ffmpeg x264
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install make automake g++ bzip2 python unzip patch subversion ruby build-essential git-core checkinstall yasm texi2html libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libvdpau-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev zlib1g-dev
```

installing x264

```
sudo git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git
cd x264
sudo ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

installing libvpx

```
sudo wget http://webm.googlecode.com/files/libvpx-v0.9.7-p1.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf libvpx-v0.9.7-p1.tar.bz2
cd libvpx-v0.9.7-p1
sudo ./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
```

***check if /etc/ld.so.conf contains the lines `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`. if not then add them and save it***

then run

```
sudo ldconfig
```

installing ffmpeg

```
sudo wget http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-0.8.10.tar.bz2
sudo tar xvjf ffmpeg-0.8.10.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg-0.8.10
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libfaac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
sudo ldconfig
```

in your project you should include the headers in this way:

```
#include<libavformat/avformat.h>
#include<libavcodec/avcodec.h>
```

In eclipse you should add the ffmpeg libraries to your project: avutil, avformat, avcodec, m, z ... by going to project->properties->C/C++->Build->Settings->GCC C++-> Linker->Libraries

I hope this works for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to link them with your code. Use -l and -L gcc command line parameters in your make file, or edit the properties for your Eclipse project (go to the project properties->C/C++->Build->Settings->GCC C++-> Linker->Libraries.

Answer (score 1):

if the includes and libraries that you want are in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` respectively, seems that you are covered with include and library paths (these directories are in the default search path usually).

Verify that you didn't use `lib...` when specifying the library that you want to link to, this is prepended by default, e.g. to use `libabc.a` just specify `abc` in the library list of the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting compile errors (not linker errors), make sure libav* folders reside in `/usr/local/include` and you include ffmpeg headers with their folder names.

```
#include libavformat/avformat.h 
#include libavcodec/avcodec.h
// ...
```

You have to define `/usr/local/include` as an include directory and not libav* folders inside. This is needed because ffmpeg headers themselves reference other headers this way.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is dependent on platform.
2. You have to properly configure the ffmpeg libraries with all the right flags mingw/or cygwin. you would get .a files recognizable by eclipse.
3. as littleadv says you must configure the path to the ffmeg libraries.  in the project ->build properties- include(ffmpeg folderand your mingw/cygwin local include ) and linker settings avformat avcodec avfilter avdevice swscale postproc .
4. Do not forget to set the path variable in your os. Eclipse takes this. Path should point to lib and include /local  mingw/cygwin.