# How to link Eclipse Indigo in Ubuntu 11 to FFMPEG 8 for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, ffmpeg, linker-errors

I have tried everything in the book and EVERYTHING I could find on how to do this and reinstalled and reconfigured and rebuilt several times to no avail. This is what I have. I've made FFMPEG on my Ubuntu VM and have the following code written:

```
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

    avcodec_register_all();

    return 0;
}
```

This errors and says:

```
/home/adam/workspace/MP4 Tools/Debug/../testDriver.cpp:19: undefined reference to     `avcodec_register_all()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have included the libavcodec.a file. Project->Properties->GCC C++ Linker->Libraries->add "avcodec"

Can anyone think of something I'm not doing or overlooking? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070155/linux-eclipse-c-how-to-connect-ffmpeg-libs-to-your-project)

but don't forget that if you use c++ you should include ffmpeg headers in this way:

```
extern "C"{
#include<libavformat/avformat.h>
#include<libavcodec/avcodec.h>
}
```